# How to make @Indexed as unique property for Redis model using Spring JPA Repository?

Tags: spring, jpa, redis, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-redis

I have a model class that I store in Redis and I use Jpa Repository with Spring java. Normally(not with redis) jpa repository is saving the new data or updates(conditionally) if the given model is already exist in Db. Here, I want to add new item to redis but if it is not already exists on db otherwise update it just like usual Jpa implementation.

Here is my model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@RedisHash("MyRecord")
public class MyRecordRedisModel {


    private String id;

    @Id
    @Indexed
    private String recordName;

    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

}
```

And my repository class is just a normal spring jpa repo as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface IFRecordRedisRepository extends JpaRepository<IFRecordRedisModel, String> {

    Page<IFRecordRedisModel> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Unique key must be the name (I totally do not care about uniquiness of the id). Thus, if the name is already exist in Db than do not add it again. I marked it as ***Indexed*** but still it is adding same data (with same recordName).

How can I make it unique?

Answer (score 0):

This would require an additional query, but I think this solution would work for you. You can use query by Example to check if there exists a record with that name, and save conditionally, or do something else if it already exists.

```
IFRecordRedisModel exampleRecord = new IFRecordRedisModel();
exampleRecord.setRecordName(inputRecord.getRecordName());
if (!repository.exists(Example.of(exampleModel))) 
    repository.save(inputRecord);
else ..... // do something else
```